# How to change excel tabs names in a R code

Tags: r, excel

The code below merges two spreadsheets into one. This works great, however I would like to make a brief modification. The final excel generated has the following tabs: Calculation and Test. However, I would like to change the name of these tabs to CALCULATION and TEST of the final generated spreadsheet. How to do this?

```
library(readxl)
library(openxlsx)

df1<-read_excel('C:/Users/Jose/Desktop/Calculation.xlsx',sheet = "Calculation")
df2<-read_excel('C:/Users/Jose/Desktop/Test.xlsx',sheet = "Test")

wb <- createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(wb,"Calculation")
writeData(wb,sheet = "Calculation", x=df1)
addWorksheet(wb,"Test")
writeData(wb,sheet = "Test", x=df2)
saveWorkbook(wb,file = "AllData.xlsx")
```

Comment: From the openxlsx documentation "renameWorksheet(wb, sheet, newName)"?

Comment: I don't understand the point of the question, tbh: you explicitly control the sheet naming in this code using static strings, so it seems obvious that you control the names. If you want to do this programmatically, it's also not difficult to use `toupper(.)`, but still, this isn't about changing excel tabs names, it's about getting them right the first time. Am I missing something, Antonio?

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Then after I saw that the resolution was easy, I just put `names(wb) <- c("CALCULATION", "TEST")` before `saveWorkbook`